# change transition of navigationcontroller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

In the typical viewcontroller transition both views, the disappear and appear view are moving, but now I want to create a custom animation where you throw the event to change of view, the view that will disappear, just hide without transition and animation, and the view will appear continue with the same transition.
then the problem here is I have navigation bar and I don't know, how can I create a custom transition of navigation bar?, 
can you help me to know how to change or remove the transition of navigation controller.

I've try it but it only add other transition and don't remove the base transition.

For Push:

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                 animations:^{
                                 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView   animated:NO];
                                 [UIView     setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight    forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                             }];
```

For Pop:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                 animations:^{
                                 [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                                 [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition  forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                             }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

any ideas? thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can just use add as subview and have title bar to mimic like navigation controller.

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
//setup frame 
nextView.view.frame = xxx;
[self.view addSubview:nextView.view];
```

Remove using `[nexView.view removeFromSuperView];`

OR

Just add some view above your current view with default hidden and set hidden NO on some action  or call bringSubviewFront method if you want to keep view below and bring in front on some action.

Comment: thanks for your comment, where can I put it, in each view ? or in view navigation controller ? and when you say nextView.view.frame = xxx; the xxx are a CGRect()?

Comment: If you want to show "nextView" on your current view only then yes on view. But if it is going to be used elsewhere also use navigation controllers. And hide navigation title bar. Yes xxx CGRect()